# Regex for pattern matching in XSD

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am writing XSD pattern restriction and I have the following strings that are valid

1. $name
2. {.newvalue}
3. {testing}
4. $name.testing

And the below are invalid

1. {$testing}
2. $testing}
3. {testing

No uppercase or @ symbol allowed.

I have tried this `<xs:pattern value="\{\w?[a-z0-9A-Z\.]*\}|\$\w+(\.[\w]+)*"/>` this work partially but doesn't satisfy all conditions

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
<xs:pattern value="\$[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*|\{\.?[a-z0-9]+\}" />
```

The XSD regex is always anchored at the string start/end, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/clbPe4/1/).

**Details**

- `\$[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*` - `$`, one or more lowercase ASCII letters and then zero or mre sequences of a dot and one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `\{\.?[a-z0-9]+\}` - `{`, an optional `.`, then 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters and then a `}` char.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor as with the last time this works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Try `\{?\$?[a-z.]+\}?`

It's not easy to work out what the actual rules are: your attempted regex allows digits, but none of the examples use digits; and your attempted regex explicitly allows upper case, but your text suggests upper case isn't allowed. And why do you mention '@' specifically, and not other punctuation characters?